# What is varying lowp float vT

Tags: glsl

I'm trying to understand graph example in QT and stuck on some stuff. 
GLSL vertex and frag shader are used to draw a graph.

Here's the vertex shader code:

```
attribute highp vec4 pos;
attribute highp float t;

uniform lowp float size;
uniform highp mat4 qt_Matrix;

varying lowp float vT;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 adjustedPos = pos;
    adjustedPos.y += (t * size );
    gl_Position = qt_Matrix * adjustedPos;

    vT = t;
}
```

What is vT???

Also,

```
struct LineVertex {
    float x, y, t;
    inline void set(float xx, float yy, float tt) {x = xx; y = yy; t = tt;}
};


void LineNode::updateGeometry(const QRectF &bounds, const QList<qreal> &samples) {

    m_geometry.allocate(samples.size() * 2);

    qreal x = bounds.x();
    qreal y = bounds.y();
    qreal w = bounds.width();
    qreal h = bounds.height();

    qreal dx = w / (samples.size() - 1);


    LineVertex *v = (LineVertex *) m_geometry.vertexData();

    for(int i = 0; i < samples.size(); ++i) {
        v[i*2 + 0].set(x + dx * i, y + samples.at(i) * h, 0);
        v[i*2 + 1].set(x + dx * i, y + samples.at(i) * h, 1);
    }
    markDirty(QSGNode::DirtyGeometry);
}
```

I can't understand why in for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < samples.size(); ++i) {
        v[i*2 + 0].set(x + dx * i, y + samples.at(i) * h, 0);
        v[i*2 + 1].set(x + dx * i, y + samples.at(i) * h, 1);
    }
```

they are creating a pair of vertices with identical positions and adding `t*size` (which is 0 on first of the pair and 1 to second one) 
Isn't that enough that x,y positions are tweaked properly

I tried to comment `adjustedPos.y += (t * size );` and graph just disappered.

Comment: What part of `vT` is unclear? Also, a lot in your question depends on stuff you don't even show. Please at least try to extract a [mcve]. As a new user, also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: `vT` is passed to the fragment shader. It will smoothly interpolate from one part of the line to another. We cannot tell you what it does without seeing your fragment shader.

Comment: Assuming you are looking at [this shader](https://github.com/mburakov/qt5/tree/master/qtdeclarative/examples/quick/scenegraph/graph/shaders/line.fsh) (next time please add a link to it), the [corresponding fragment shader](https://github.com/mburakov/qt5/blob/master/qtdeclarative/examples/quick/scenegraph/graph/shaders/line.fsh#L51-L53) tells us that `vT` is used to calculate the coefficients for a gradient in the resulting line.